# git log shows an unmerged changeset

Tags: git

The following should not be possible, right?  How can a branch contain a changeset, but a cherry-pick of that actually do something?  I checked, there are no merges or changes that reverted this changeset...

```
➜  SourceRoot git:(release-HOTFIX-7) git branch --contains ade53bfdd9d5fae7b16ccfa5feaba451fc229565
develop
* release-HOTFIX-7
release-13
release-14

➜  SourceRoot git:(release-HOTFIX-7) git cherry-pick ade53bfdd9d5fae7b16ccfa5feaba451fc229565
[release-HOTFIX-7 aa060d4] JIRA-1427
Author: some-poor-developer's name
6 files changed, 41 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
create mode 100644 JavaJars/jzlib-1.1.2.jar
```

What are some of the things that I should do to prevent a dropped changeset in the future?  I must have done something wrong?

edit - reply to Antak's comment below

```
commit d5855051fa2c779df553a4a388928e80f822bb36
Author: <some_poor_dev's_name>
Date:   Wed Jul 17 15:26:21 2013 -0700

    #comment redacted

A       AntJavaJars/jzlib-1.1.2.jar
```

and that's it.  the file itself claims to be added by the cherry-pick.

Comment: Perhaps those particular changes had been undone in some way (reverted or other merges/changes that superseded them) between the time it was originally merged/cherry-picked into that branch and when you try to cherry-pick it again.

Comment: definitely not reverted.  At least, according to a git log --name-only and greping on the filename.

Comment: @JeffWang what does `git log --name-status --full-history -- <filename>` say? Also, why are you even doing this? What inspired you to check if a commit exists in a branch, then to cherry-pick that commit into the branch again?

Comment: What does `git log ade53bfdd~.. --name-status -- JavaJars/jzlib-1.1.2.jar` tell you?

Comment: @Cupcake - I don't have --full-history yet.  still on git 1.7

Answer (score 1):

`git branch --contains` won't lie. That commit is most ***definitely*** merged into that branch somewhere.  It looks like you're just adding the same changes that it introduced twice. Have you looked at the result of the cherry-pick? What happened to the files that it touched?

Comment: (includes reply to the comment you have above) - The original problem was that we couldn't find the jzlib  in the classpath.  and looking at the code, the changeset was not reflected.  After the cherry-pick, the changeset was refelcted and the jzlib jar is now there.